# What happens if I tap Aetherling to attack and in my 2nd main phase I exile it?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm talking about this card:

[image: Aetherling]

In my interpretation if I exile it after I tapped it to attack I instantly get it back untapped before the opponent's turn starts.

Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are correct.

as long as you activate the exile ability before your end step, it will return untapped before your opponent's turn.

It does not return instantly however, if you exile it during your turn e.g. during the combat phase, it will not return until your end step. If you wish to cast sorcery or creature cards with it on the battlefield, you will not be able to until your next turn.

Comment: So if I active the ability between my combat and end step it will act like vigiliance.

Comment: essentially yes, as long as you wait until after damage is dealt (if you want it to deal damage). You will have it as a blocker on the next turn.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you are correct: you can use the ability at any time, and it always returns on the end step; if you used it just before the end step it would come right back.

This would be very handy if someone suprises you with a flash or instant when you attack, as it would be for blocking seeing as you can pull it out once blockers have been declared but before damage is resolved.